# $wpdb->get_results() returns good result only in first foreach iteration

Tags: wpdb

I've got strange issue when I am using $wpdb->get_results() in content-single.php in Twenty Eleven theme. `$wpdb->get_results()` returns proper values only in first loop iteration. I've got simple function in `functions.php` called

```
function get_product_data($postid)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $meta_table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
    $product_table = $wpdb->prefix.'_features';

    $eans = get_post_meta($postid, '_bs_prod_sym');
    $eans = explode(';', $eans[0]);

    print_r($eans); // returns Array ( [0] => abcde [1] => abcd )
    foreach($eans as $ean)
    {
        $features = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT feature_name FROM $product_table WHERE product_id = '$ean'", ARRAY_A);  

        print_r($features);// returns Array ( [0] => Array ( [feature_name] =>  feature name 1 ) [1] => Array ( [feature_name] => feature name 2 ) [2] => Array ( [feature_name] => feature name 3 ) ) 

        foreach($features as $feature) 
        {  
            print_r($feature); // returns single element of $features array
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the place in content-single.php where I am calling `get_product_data()`.

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php get_product_data(get_the_ID()); ?>

        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Query in `$features` variable returns proper values only in first foreach iteration. If I change values in array `$eans` to `Array ( [0] => abcd [1] => abcde )` (before it was `Array ( [0] => abcde [1] => abcd )`) I get proper values also only once. I am sure that queries are good and data in database are also ok.

Comment: `print_r($feature)` returns `Array ( [feature_name] =>  feature name 1 )` and then stops? Nothing else? If `$features` look like your code comment says it does, that makes no sense.

Comment: Check that items in `$eans` after `explode()` don't have lingering whitespace in them.

Comment: I'm assuming `$features` is what it should return, as if it did return that, your code would work. Try `var_dump($ean)` in your first loop and make sure that the length is good (i.e. no whitespace, as @Rarst mentioned). If you have whitespace, replace `$ean` with `trim($ean)` in the `foreach()` statement.

Comment: As an aside, your function seems to be doing nothing other than querying, yet you are running lots of individual queries. Far more efficient to run on query and order the results.